# Editing CSS of twitter timeline widget iframe

Tags: html, css, twitter

Hello I was trying to edit the css of the twitter timeline widget, I was trying to edit the padding of the `.tweet` part, I want to use width 100% but make the tweets appear centered, so I made something like

```
#twitter-widget-0.tweet  {
    padding: 12px 12px 10px 69px !important; 
}
```

but didn´t work.
The jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/pscxjeem/8/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
html,body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.tw-align-center {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.timeline, #twitter-widget-0, .tw-align-center { 
  width: 100% !important; 
}
#twitter-widget-0.tweet  {
  padding: 12px 12px 10px 69px !important; 

}
```